# Initialize new objects in a loop based on a number entered by the user

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a `LinkedList` of type car, and I have a function in that class to enter data about the car. I want to ask the user how many cars he wants to store in the `LinkedList` so that I can create objects based on that number, then call the function on each object. I couldn't figure out how to initiate the objects according to the user number. This is what I could come up with:

```
LinkedList<Car> my_car = new LinkedList <Car>();
System.out.println("How many cars you want to store?:");
int car_num = key.nextInt();
for(int i=0 ; i<car_num ; i++)
{
 my_car.add(new Car());
 //this doesn't work because it just adds empty Car objects 
 //I couldn't figure out how to call .Enter_car_data() 
 //function here for each object created
}
```

One of my friends told me that I can use one object then add it to the 
`LinkedList`, and reuse it again! It didn't work, because when I wanted to display the `LinkedList` elements, it only shows the same data multiple time.

Any help please.

Comment: You can instantiate like this: Car c = new Car(); Then call c.Enter_car_data(), and then add to list my_car.add(c); Hope this helps with the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a new variable within the loop.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<car_num ; i++)
{
    Car car = new Car();
    car.doSomething(); //use your modifying method here
    my_car.add(car);
}
```

Comment: Or get user input at the top of the loop, and then call the Car constructor that allows parameters (if one exists).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices.

**Direct creation**
You can create the Car, call the Enter_car_data method and add the car to the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < car_num; i++) 
{
    Car car = new Car();
    car.Enter_car_data();
    my_car.add(car);
}
```

**Use another method** 
Move the creation and population of the car to a dedicated method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < car_num; i++) 
{
    Car car = getCar();
    my_car.add(car);
}
```

Elsewhere in your class, you would then have a `getCar()` method.

```
private Car getCar()
{
    Car car = new Car();
    car.Enter_car_data();
    return car;
}
```

This approach is a little more verbose, but it help to give you more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Car car = new Car();
enterCarData(car);
my_car.add(car);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either do what people are saying, that is assign it to a temporary variable then initialize

```
Car tmp = new Car();
tmp.enter_car_data();
my_car.add(tmp);
```

Or you can define the default constructor of the car class to do what enter_car_data would do.

```
public Car(){
    this.enter_car_data()
}
```